# "haber cuéntame" = "so, tell me". Why is it translated like this?

Tags: coloquialismos, infinitivo, haber

The verb *haber* has always confused me in its infinitive form. So in this construct of *haber cuéntame*, I see it is translated as "so, tell me".

I have just memorized that, but it makes no sense to me. I would expect *así, cuéntame* or *así pues, cuéntame*. Can someone break this down and project this to other sayings that use haber in this way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is not "<del>haber, cuéntame</del>", but "a ver, cuéntame". The meaning of [a ver](https://dle.rae.es/ver#AJGrKLN) is

> 1. expr. U. para pedir algo que se quiere reconocer o ver.

i.e., it is used to ask to be shown or told something. It is roughly equivalent to "let's see/hear it" or "let me see/hear it" or "so", depending on the context.

Comment: I got my original phrase from a text conversation with someone from Dominican Republic. So glad I asked. Thanks!

Comment: The confusion is totally understandable, even for some native speakers with bad spelling, as "haber" and "a ver" are homophones.

Comment: @PaulW I also know some natives that make that mistake. It is more common than one would think...

Comment: You mean they make the mistake in **writing**, right?

Comment: @Lambie yes, when writing in chats

Comment: Yeah, it is funny, isn't it?

Comment: It's really hard to make that mistake when speaking

Comment: Could that also be an autocorrect error, rather than an error on the part of the texter?

Comment: @chepner that seems unlikely: at least my auto-corrector corrects word by word, and never replaces two words with one.

Comment: @wimi: it could be a combination of Autocorrect and the texter; e.g. if they wrote *aber* (of perhaps even *aver*) Autocorrect might then have changed it to *haber*.

Comment: It feels to me as an analog error to English speakers who write *should of* instead of *should have*. It doesn't make sense, but people write it anyway.

Comment: I had a Spanish teacher that would start each lesson with "vamos a ver" - I always thought it was a really good way to kick off with "let's all learn some stuff."

Comment: Or could have been speech to text which just writes what it bears and often doesn't make sense

Comment: It's most definitely a mistake made by the writer. As a Spanish native speaker, I know more people that I'd like to know who don't understand the difference between "haber", "a ver", and "aber" (which doesn't exist but anyway).

It's also common when writing "ahí", "hay" and "ay".

Comment: @ParibusCeteris is it? after all "v" and "b" might sound "equal" but are actually prononunced differently i.e. using a slightly different mouth movement. I think it's just that (we) native speakers have either forgotten that or not noticed it when speaking.

Comment: @JoshPart as far as I know, for most native Spanish speakers (at least those in Spain), "b" and "v" are pronounced equally. This is [confirmed by RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/v) (see point 3).